# Prevent hn tags default formatting

Tags: html, css

The h1, h2, ... h6 tags seem to apply automatic formatting to the page, adding a new line wherever used. Can I define a CSS property in order to avoid it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can I define a CSS property in order to avoid it

Of course. Just make `CSS` for your element

```
h3 {
 display: inline;
 // next CSS properties
}​
```

Answer (score 0):

yes now you can define the css code of all heading tag

as like this

```
        h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6{
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:top;
 /////////////////css style
        }
```

Comment: I appreciate your effort in answering me, but your answer is not related to my question at all.